# What is meaning of <FunctionImport> in OData Metadata?

Tags: odata

After I went through OData doc, I still do not understand the meaning of `<FunctionImport>`.

1. What is that used for?
   Some one said that "Function imports are used to perform custom operations on a JPA entity in addition to CRUD operations. For example, consider a scenario where you would like to check the availability of an item to promise on the sales order line items. ATP check is a custom operation that can be exposed as a function import in the schema of OData service."

But I think above requirement can be achieved by general `<Function>` also, right?

2. What is the difference between `<FunctionImport>` and `<Function>` exactly?

I do appreciate anyone's help!
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three types of functions in OData:

1. Functions that are bound to something (e.g. an entity). Example would be

   `GET http://host/service/Products(1)/Namespace.GetCategories()`

   such function is defined in the metadata using the `<function>` element and with its `isBound` attribute set to `true`.
2. Unbound functions. They are usually used in queries. E.g.

   `GET http://host/service/Products?$filter(Name eq Namespace.GetTheLongestProductName())`

   such function is defined in the metadata using the `<function>` element with its `isBound` attribute set to `false`
3. Function imports. They are the functions that can be invoked at the service root. E.g. 

   `GET http://host/service/GetMostExpensiveProduct()`

   Their concept is a little bit similar as the concept of static functions in program languages, and they are defined in metadata using the `<functionimport>` element.

Similar distinguishing applies to `<action>` and `<actionimport>` as well.

Comment: In my case, `<FunctionImport>` is not appearing, any idea ? Even though I have added `oDataJPACtx.setJPAEdmExtension((JPAEdmExtension) new ProcessingExtension());`

Answer (score 4):

OK, I got the answer by myself.
`<OData Version 4.0 Part 1: Protocol Plus Errata 02>`:
Operations allow the execution of custom logic on parts of a data model. Functions are operations that do not have side effects and may support further composition, for example, with additional filter operations, functions or an action. Actions are operations that allow side effects, such as data modification, and cannot be further composed in order to avoid non-deterministic behavior. Actions and functions are either bound to a type, enabling them to be called as members of an instance of that type, or unbound, in which case they are called as static operations. Action imports and function imports enable unbound actions and functions to be called from the service root.